# Python Method Placement

Tags: python

Can someone give me a solution to this

```
dosomething()

def dosomething():
    print 'do something'
```

I don't want my method defines up at the top of the file, is there a way around this?

Comment: What is wrong with having them at the top? You should also never have your runnable code in the bare module area, instead encapsulate it into a main() function that you call under an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block. This allows your script to be importable to allow for easier code reuse.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The "standard" way is to do things inside a `main` function at the top of your file and then call `main()` at the bottom. E.g.

```
def main():
    print 'doing stuff'
    foo()
    bar()

def foo():
    print 'inside foo'

def bar():
    print 'inside bar'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

if `if __name__ == '__main__':` part ensures that `main()` won't be called if the file is imported into another python program, but is only called when the file is run directly.

Of course, "main" doesn't mean anything... (`__main__` does, however!) It's a psuedo-convention, but you could just as well call it `do_stuff`, and then have `if __name__ == '__main__': do_stuff()` at the bottom.

Edit: You might also want to see [Guido's advice on writing `main`'s](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=4829).  Also, Daenyth makes an excellent point (and beat me to answering): The reason why you should do something like this isn't that is "standard" or even that it allows you to define functions below your "main" code.  The reason you should do it is that it encourages you to write *modular and reusable* code.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from adding the definition of `dosomething` to a separate file and importing it:

```
from my_module import dosomething

dosomething()
```

I don't believe there is any other way ... but I could be wrong.